# Design pattern for object-relational mapping

Tags: java, android, database, oop

I have several related database tables and I would like to treat their rows as objects and their tables as something like lists.  What are the considerations that I have to keep in mind (for instance, ensuring that the objects stay consistent with one another and with the database, lazy loading)?  And what is a good design pattern for implementing this?  As I imaging the answer is pretty involved, a link to a good website would suffice.

On the other hand, if someone knows of Hibernate-like thing *that really works* on Android, I might give that a whirl (although it's a little heavy weight for me right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best places to look for *best practices* on this subject is **Chapter 31 - Object persistence and databases** in [Object-Oriented Software Construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554) by Bertrand Meyer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have particular reasons for taking this approach, but it's not necessarily the right thing to do. See, for example http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FirstGreatBlunder

I don't know much about Andriod, but for straight java development I prefer libraries such as EmpireDB http://incubator.apache.org/empire-db/ to O/R mapping frameworks. A database is, after all, a tool designed to do data manipulation.